# Go and SQL parameters

Tags: sql, go

I have a problem with parameters to an SQL query. In this case I'm getting unexpected results from an ORDER BY query. I'm running PostgreSQL[1] on OSX and go v1.0.3.

I have a table with two columns: *name varchar, gophers int*

Inserted rows are: ("Alice", 2) and ("Bob", 1)

If I run my query like this: `rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM foo ORDER BY gophers")` I get what I want ("Bob", "Alice")

But if I run it like this `rows, err = db.Query("SELECT name FROM foo ORDER BY $1", "gophers")` I get them by insertion order ("Alice", "Bob")

Why?

Complete code: http://paste2.org/p/2537881

[1] https://github.com/bmizerany/pq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that this is a go issue at all. In psql I did

```
PREPARE  test (text) AS SELECT name FROM foo  ORDER BY $1;
EXECUTE test('a');
```

and I got

```
 name  
 -------
 alice
 bob
 (2 rows)
```

I am wondering if you can do ORDER BY $1. I Google this a bit but could not find anything usefully. I know this is not an answer but it would seem to me this might be the issue. I wish I could find something of if ORDER BY supports parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint masebase. I have contacted the pq developer. If it's a pgsql issue (which it probably is) I will see if I can find an answer from the postgresql camp, and post my findings here.